# Redmine Email through SES SMTP

Tags: smtp, amazon-web-services, redmine

Has anybody successfully configured a redmine installation to send mail through Amazon SES SMTP?

My settings are:

```
production:
  email_delivery:
    delivery_method: :smtp
    smtp_settings:
      tls: true
      enable_starttls_auto: true
      address: email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
      port: 465
      domain: example.com
      authentication: :plain
      user_name: ***
      password: ***
```

When I try to send a test email through the redmine settings, it just times out, with no clear errors in the log or anything.

Note, this does the same if I remove the `enable_starttls_auto: true` line.

Answer (score 6):

I've been able to get it working using `authentication: :login`.

Here is the full setup:

```
production:
  email_delivery:
    delivery_method: :smtp
    smtp_settings:
      enable_starttls_auto: true
      address: email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
      port: 587
      domain: mydomain.com
      authentication: :login
      user_name: credentials_username
      password: credentials_password
```

Just one more note: my Redmine is not set in 'mydomain.com'.

Comment: work for me but:
if you get (535 Authentication Credentials Invalid), then create a new smtp user: [here](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ses/home#smtp-settings:)

Comment: Worked for me too.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried doing that, but if your Redmine runs inside an instance you control, you can setup a local PostFix server that your redmine will talk. Configure it to respond only to local requests (127.0.0.1) and have it forward everything via SES SMTP integration. That should probably do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I have set this up as you have above and it works Redmine 1.3.2

You need the enable_starttls_auto: true and I made sure the domain is the same the one that the redmine server is setup